# Storing calculated column to use in order_by and select

Tags: elixir, ecto

So I'm doing a PostGis calculation. I have a User and a Place model. Each have a `:geom`, and Place has a virtual `distance` field. I want to order by distance, as well as select it. I have it working like this, but I'm worried it's doing the postgis calc twice. Is there a better way to do this?

```
from(
  ...,
  order_by: [asc: st_distance(u.geom, p.geom)], 
  select: %{p | distance: st_distance(u.geom, p.geom)}
)
```

Comment: Do you have evidence it's calculating it twice? I would assume Postgresql would be able to re-use the order_by expression in the select

Comment: @m3characters I don't have evidence of that. Was just curious if there was a better way to do this. But you might be right that it sees that the calc has already been done and just uses that.

Comment: I was just asking because you could have made some tests and saw that it took more time, which would hint that maybe it was doing extra work? If that was the case perhaps you could use a fragment for the select field and alias it and then use a fragment referring to that same name as the order by?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alias to reuse that calculated value, although you'll have to use fragments. It's not such a tradeoff! [This article](https://angelika.me/2016/09/10/how-to-order-by-the-result-of-select-count-in-ecto/) details the logic nicely.

In your use case, it would give something like this:

```
from(
  ...,
  order_by: [asc: fragment("distance")], 
  select: %{p | distance: fragment("? AS distance", st_distance(u.geom, p.geom))}
)
```